# Obtendo id e nome de um array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, array

Estou recebendo uma resposta da minha API que é um array contendo algumas informações entre elas `idTipoTitulo` e `nome` ocorre que eu preciso somente desses dois atributos para exibir na tela.

Meu método

```
$http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : '/user/tiposTitulos', 
        }).then(function(response) {
            $scope.tiposTitulos= response.data;


        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.status);
        });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E qual é a duvida? Saber como iterar `$scope.tiposTitulos` para compilar o HTML?

Comment: @Sergio sim.......

Comment: Como assim _"sim......."_? qual é a parte que não sabes como fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função map no client para isso, algo como:

```
 var arrayDoBack = [
    {codigoDne: "0186", idTipoTitulo: 164, nome: "cacacaca"},
    {codigoDne: "123", idTipoTitulo: 123, nome: "tesxt"},
    {codigoDne: "1245", idTipoTitulo: 159, nome: "asdasdasd"},
    {codigoDne: "5515", idTipoTitulo: 654, nome: "fagaga"},
    {codigoDne: "151515", idTipoTitulo: 957, nome: "caqweagcacaca"},
    {codigoDne: "1515", idTipoTitulo: 2, nome: "hjhjks"},
    {codigoDne: "15151", idTipoTitulo: 999, nome: "amaklsaklsa"}
  ];

  var arrayReduzido = arrayDoBack.map(function(item) {
    // Retorna o objeto que vc quer, no caso idTipoTitulo e Nome.
    return {
      idTipoTitulo: item.idTipoTitulo,
      nome: item.nome
    };
  });
  console.log(arrayReduzido);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou você poderia tratar isso na API.